# Android get image from internal/external storage

Tags: android, image, imageview, bitmapfactory

I try to show my created png file in an imageView. When I start my program and click the showCreatedPng button, there is just a white blank page on emulator's screen.

And logCat says : (Maybe Logcat shows errors because of Emulator. My emulator has 200 mb sd-card but, I can not find where is the created PNG in my computer. When I start the program my phone, PNG saved in GT-I9100\Phone folder. I guess the folder is an internal folder. Anyway, I can not see my created png file. Please help.)

```
05-21 21:53:39.764: E/BitmapFactory(1335): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/*.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

These are codes that I used.

For saving :

```
private void saveImageToExternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String qrPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
    try
    {
       File dir = new File(qrPath);
       if (!dir.exists()) {
          dir.mkdirs();
       }
       OutputStream fOut = null;
       File file = new File(qrPath, "QRCode.png");
       if(file.exists()){
          file.delete();
          file.createNewFile();
          fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
          fOut.flush();
          fOut.close();
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And codes for get png file :

```
 String qrPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/*.png";
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
 Bitmap mustOpen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(qrPath, options);

 setContentView(R.layout.qr_image);
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qr_image);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(mustOpen);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open a file called `*.png`. This should probably be `QRCode.png`, thus the code

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/QRCode.png";
```

Comment: Thaks a lot :D Sometimes I can not see little things like this. :D